# What's wrong with my IR21531D H-bridge gate drive?

Tags: h-bridge

I'm new to here. I am recently making an H-bridge inverter with IR21531D ([here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/ir21531.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c8d26316b3) is the data sheet). I connected them this way:

[image]
When I measure the Lo and Ho pin with passive probe and differential probe (I only have one differential probe), and I got this 
[image]
I use the differential probe to measure the voltage between Ho and VS, and the Lo and Ho gate signal are overlapped. The dead time is too large which is not even close to the datasheet (0.6 us typ.). If I connect my FET, the circuit will short together.

Can any master here could help me out? Thank you.

Comment: Is the switching frequency matching that of your calculations?

Comment: The frequency is determined by the timing resistor and timing capacitor, according to the data sheet, i am having the correct frequency.

Comment: Any difference if you load the outputs slightly? Say 47 kohm Lo to ground and Ho to Vs?

Comment: The FET gate is able to take up the voltage from Ho and Lo. Anyway, I rebuilt the circuit and things are fine now. Thank you very much for your attention!